# nginx error "rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting"

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nginx

I want to run 2 different website on my localhost running on nginx and node.js, for that I have write following nginx file.

sites-available/default

```
upstream app_site1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;  
    keepalive 80;
}

upstream app_site2 {
    server 127.0.0.1:3002;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /home/user/workspace/site1;
    index index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    access_log /dev/null;
    #error_log  /var/log/stat-error.log;

        # static resources
        location ~ ^/(robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
            root /home/user/workspace/statistics;
            access_log on;
            expires max;
        }

    location = /favicon.ico {
        root /home/user/workspace;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    location ~ /js/(.*) {
            add_header X-debug-message "A static file was served by pushstate";

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy     true;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass         http://app_stat;
        }

        location ~ /socket.io/(.*) {
           add_header X-debug-message "A static file was served by pushstate";

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy     true;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass         http://app_stat;
        }

       location ~ ^/(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
            add_header X-debug-message "A static file was served by pushstate";

            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
            proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy     true;

            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_pass         http://app_stat;
        }

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules

            if ($http_user_agent ~ (Googlebot|google|bing|yandex|msnbot|AltaVista|DuckDuckBot) ) {
               return 403;
            }

                add_header X-debug-message $http_accept;
             # break;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
                proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy     true;

                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

                proxy_pass         http://app_stat;
    }
}

# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration

server {
    listen 3002;
    #listen [::]:3002 ipv6only=on;

    root /home/user/workspace/site2/;
    #index index.html;

    server_name 192.168.1.201;

    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

    # static resources
    location ~ ^/(robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
    root /home/user/workspace/site2/;
        access_log on;
        expires max;
    }

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules

        if ($http_user_agent ~ (Googlebot|google|bing|yandex|msnbot|AltaVista|DuckDuckBot) ) {
           return 403;
        }

        try_files $uri $uri/ /public/index.html$request_uri;
        #index index.html;

        add_header X-debug-message $http_accept;
        # break;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header   Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy     true;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        #proxy_pass         http://app_site2;
    }
}
```

but it's shows me following:

```
 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/public/index.html/css/login.css"
```

My folder structure in my application has

```
site2
   node_modules
   public
       html
       css
       js
       ....
   ....
   app.js
   package.json
   index.html
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="center">
            <input id='username' type="username" placeholder="Username">
            <input id='password' type="password" placeholder="Password">
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have mentioned path for the css & script is "css" & "js" folder in public, but in nginx error log, it shows me "/public/index.html/css/login.css". why it include index.html as folder? where is my mistek? I am new with nginx.

Thanks

Comment: This regular expression `location ~ ^/(.+?)(/.*)?$` matches with almost any king of "slash seperated" strings, `/public/index.html/css/login.css` included. It might cause your server to "accept" some badly-formed URLs or whatever your server configuration can do with it.

Comment: `try_files $uri $uri/ /public/index.html$request_uri;` makes internal redirect to `/public/index.html` which then ends up in the same location. I guess you don't have `/public.index.html` file.

Comment: @A.Gille, my first server part is working fine. I have problem with site2

Comment: @AlexeyTen, where I have to made change?